Unclear on all the scenarios of when a Reentrancy Attack can occur
I understand the straight forwards situation if you contract uses an external contract function to assist in transfering ether and the transfer happens before the state is updated then the attacker can have their recive function repeatedly call the transfer function to drain the contract before the state is updated.
What I am unclear on is the following scenarios

what if it is a a public transfer() function that does not make any calls to external contracts and the logic is all internal can a rentrancy attack still occur ?

what if the same scenario as 1. but it is an erc-20 and not ether

what if it is the same scanerio as I described at the intro but instead of using an external call to transfer the ether its used to transfer an erc-20


for example here in the open zeplin template they dont use a reentrancy gaurd as it is transfering an erc-20 with only internal logic so I am wondering why a reentracny would not work here for example
  function transfer(address to, uint256 value) public virtual returns (bool) {
        address owner = _msgSender();
        _transfer(owner, to, value);
        return true;
    }

